# How to remove vuetify card on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have added a vuetify card and a button on it. **I want that when the button is clicked, the card disappears. How can I do that?**

Below is how my component looks like. I want to add a method to do so but don't know what the method will be.

```
<template>
  <div class="notifications">
    <v-layout>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
        <v-card flat color="green">

          <v-card-title primary-title>
            <div>
              <h3 class="headline">Neu Benutzer angelegt</h3>
              <div> {{ card_text }} </div>
            </div>
          </v-card-title>

          <v-card-actions>
            <div class="close"><v-btn @click="removeMessage(2)">Ok</v-btn></div>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        card_text: 'Success!'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      removeMessage(seconds) {

      },
    },
  };

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide it with `v-if` and a boolean flag:

```
<template>
  <div class="notifications" v-if="show">
    <v-layout>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
        <v-card flat color="green">

          <v-card-title primary-title>
            <div>
              <h3 class="headline">Neu Benutzer angelegt</h3>
              <div> {{ card_text }} </div>
            </div>
          </v-card-title>

          <v-card-actions>
            <div class="close"><v-btn @click="removeMessage(2)">Ok</v-btn></div>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        card_text: 'Success!',
        show:true;
      }
    },
    methods: {
      removeMessage(seconds) {
         setTimeout(()=> this.show = false, seconds * 1000);
      },
    },
  };

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `v-show` and make something like this: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QoyVbG)

Comment: But what if you have many buttons and you want to toggle them individually?